# Twilio Outbound Call - Key Numbers

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

New to Twilio here and seek twilio experts advice. I'm trying to make an outbound call to an IVR system, wait out few seconds and send keypad numbers input to initiate workflow in the other end

so far, I'm able to call into the IVR system, but how can i send number inputs? I'm assuming TwiML is the way to achieve this! Any help is much appreciated

```
    def make_call(self):

        calls = self.client.calls.create(to=MY_PHONE_NUM, from_=TW_PHONE_NUM,
                                     url='https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/<TwiML reference number>')
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Dev Evangelist here...

You can absolutely do this with TwiML. Your TwiML would need to look like the below:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>YOUR_IVR_NUMBER</Dial>
    <Pause length="AMOUNT_OF_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECONDS" />
    <Play digits="IVR_PROMPT_ENTRY" />
</Response>
```

Take a look at the [Voice TwiML section of the Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml). There are some great examples you can use to help out here. And let me know if you run into any additional issues or have additional questions.

Comment: I came up with a TwiML like this, however, the recordings stop at 5 seconds, so not able to debug, the real number is not disclosed, am i doing something wrong?<Response>
    <Record timeout="25" transcribe="true" maxLength="30" />
    <Dial>111-111-111</Dial>  
 <Pause length="15" />
   <Dial>9783</Dial>
    <Pause length="2" />
    <Dial>7</Dial>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>

Comment: My sense is that you're trying to first dial the number, then record the playback and transcribe it (to possibly parse that transcribed text), and then send along additional digits. So you would want your TwiML to be listed in that order. It would look like <Response><Dial>111-111-111</Dial><Record timeout="25" transcribe="true" maxLength="30"/><Dial>9783</Dial>...</Response>. 

Putting your record verb first will assume that you want to record something and then dial the phone number. I'm not sure that that's what you want to do. Does this help?

Comment: you are right, I'm dialing in the number, then pausing for defined seconds and sending additional digits. My bad I've used record tag before dial. Actually I'm dialing to the desired number through code as you can see in my code client.calls.create(to=MY_PHONE_NUM... and should not use the Dial tag, once the call is connected, the TwiML flow should be follow <Response>
    <Record timeout="25" maxLength="30" />
 <Pause length="15" />
   <Dial>9783</Dial>
    <Pause length="2" />
    <Dial>7</Dial>
    <Hangup/>
</Response> not sure what I'm doing wrong, as the recording last only 5 secs

Comment: I suspect that when the call connects, Twilio is capturing the first 30 seconds specified by the maxLength and then is trimming off what it thinks is silence. Mind shooting me a mail at corey@twilio.com? I think we may need to debug using the call log in the console to see what's there.

Comment: Hey team, just want to jump in in case you're still working on this. You want to use [`<Play digits="9783"/>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes-digits) rather than `<Dial>`. You can also pause for half a second for each `w` you place in the `digits` string.

Comment: Thanks Philnash, I will give that a try and get back to youy